# Change website when redirecting from another page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a main page that redirects to another page called example.com

the code of the main page is:

```
 <! DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

 <h2> Redirect to a Webpage </h2>
 <p> The replace () method replaces the current document with a new one: </p>

 <button onclick = "myFunction ()"> Replace document </button>

 <script>
 function myFunction () {
   location.replace ("https://www.example.com")
 }
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

example.com shows "Original Webpage" if you enter directly
the code for example.com is:

```
 <! DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

 <h2> Original Webpage </h2>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I want that when redirecting from the main page to example.com, example.com shows "modified page".
then you should change `<h2> Original Webpage </h2>` from main page before entering example.com

!  I don't own example.com !

Comment: without a backend to detect something like `HTTP_REFERER`, you'll need to use `localStorage` or `cookies` to store a value that you can check on an other page

Comment: You would need to *own* the page that you redirect to; you cannot modify someone else's content. This is part of the cross-domain policy.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you own example.com.

The redirecting url could include a parameter:

```js
location.replace("https://www.example.com/?redirected=true")
```

On example.com you could check if that parameter exists:

```js
if (new URL(location.href).searchParams.get('redirected')) == 'true') {
  document.querySelector('h2').textContent = "modified page"
}
```

Comment: Remember: @molo32_1 does not own example.com

Answer (score 0):

you cant change other sites' content.
If it would possible, someone could redirect user to (for example) Amazon, changing its code to hijack login/password or credit card info.

Browsers have special checks to insure content of the site in address bar is genuine